# Bad phd experience

Tags: research-process, advisor

I am a theoretical chemistry PhD student. I've been stuck on my PhD problem for the last 5 months. I told this to my supervisor at that time, but she didn't paid any attention. Even if I go and meet her, she is not interested in these things. I am doing Integrated PhD program (MS-PhD), if I quit the course I won't even get my MS degree. There is no platform where I can raise my voice. I discussed to some of my PhD friends, some of them told me that it will be better to leave. I need some advice whether I need to continue or not?

Comment: Speak to the director of graduate studies in your department.

Comment: it is common to get no progress in five months when doing research.

Comment: Being stuck on a problem throughout the entire PhD programme is common experience. I would even say (but that's of course a joke): you have been stuck for *only* 5 months?

Comment: Avoid leaving if possible; there's no way to get back in once you leave.

Comment: If your advisor isn't paying attention to you, fire her. Find another advisor.

Comment: I totally agree with @anomaly. Don't leave. Try to get another supervisor at any cost.

Comment: When you go and meet her, what does she want to talk about instead?

Comment: If it helps, I have a paper which does not progress for two years. It is a very common problem. Maybe you can try to conduct two resarch papers at same time. Doing this could decrease your stress level as you will feel more productive and better concentrate on the problem that you can not solve for the moment afterwards.

Comment: you need to change advisor.

Answer (score 4):

Your supervisor does not seem to care that much about you. In this case one would try some of these:

1) Try to handle the problem yourself. Certainly, you tried hard. But take time to take a step backward on your work and think it again. In other words, try to slowly reconsider your problem from start. This way you can come accross potentials solutions that would not tilt to your mind otherwise.

2) Don't you have any fellows PhD or PostDoc around ? Any other experienced people ? A fresh opinion is always appreciated.

3) Books. Nowadays, many people neglect this resource over the great Internet. However, they often treat with specific problems, on which examples are seldom on the Web.

4) *Think positive*.

Comment: Big upvote for books. Our institute library has a wealth of stuff that's often hard to find through the online subscriptions.

Comment: Agree with @LLlAMnYP. Books are often more organized  and more in depth than the resources on the Internet. +1

Comment: @scaaahu It's not that the internet is of lower quality, no, journal papers and downloadable books are fine. I wasn't even thinking of any other resources (e.g. Wiki). But how often do I find a reference to a book, which I cannot track down online, yet it's there in our library.